# Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/test-wv/index.html

Tags: android

I load html in assets dir, here is my code:

/home/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-adr/app/src/main/java/ro/adr/test/TestWv.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_wv);
    WebView w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.w);
    w.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test-wv/index.html");
}
```

I'm sure this html file exist

/home/roroco/Dropbox/jvs/ro-adr/app/src/main/assets/test-wv/index.html

Comment: I didn't know that the HTML had to be in /src/main/assets/index.html but you had to refer to it as "file:///android_asset/index.html

Answer (score 2):

the reason is "instant run", In my first launch webview, the assets/ is empty, so when i add index.html to assets/, "instant run" will not refresh assets/ modification, the solution:

- way 1: clear instant run
  I must:

  gradle :app:uninstallDebug

and rerun debug

- way 2: disable instant run(in intellij idea > settings > instant run > turn off "enable instant run ..."

if you wanna write webapp in assets like me, disable instant run, if no java code is modified, "enable instant run" and "disable instant run" will spend same build time in my code